# WEB API & BL relations

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, architecture

My project structure is Client <=> Web API <=> BL <=> DAL (Repository) <=> DB.

Does it make sense that one API will know many BLs? Meaning that in one API method it will call to X_BL and in another method, at the same API class it will call to Y_BL? If it makes sense, can you please provide an example?

Or is it always should be 1:1 relation, so that each API controller will call to its BL, for example: CustomersAPI will always call to CustomersBL, and ProductsAPI will always call to ProductsBL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the answer it's **depends**, there are many questions that need to be answered first

1. What do you make a API for ?
2. Do you have to follow the architectural design patterns owned by API users (E.g. MobileApp, WebApp) ?
3. Or just want to make an API that only provides data in like you said, 1:1 relation, so the other app must follow the architectural design patterns you make ?
4. Where you focus on processing data, client side or server side ?
5. What are the limits of the work scope of the API and its users ?

In my experiences, if you want to make a **scalable REST API**, your controller **must be able** to access **any BLL** (Business Logic Layer) when it's needed. BLL = BL (in your case)

E.g. :

```
http://localhost/customers/15
```

The customers controller only needs 1 BLL (CustomerBLL) to find a customer with ID 15 then return the result. Like you said, 1:1 relation.

In the other case, you'll need more than 1 BLL.

E.g. :

```
http://localhost/customers/15/products
```

The customers controller needs another BLL (ProductsBLL) to find any products that related to customers with ID 15 then return the result.

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely makes sense, APIs often require multiple pieces of business logic to solve a particular problem.  For example, your CustomersAPI may talk to a CustomersBL, but also talk to a UsersBL to get the authorization context (which customers can be returned), or to a CRM BL when actions are performed.